# Difference between system.log and exception.log

Tags: magento-1.9, log, system.xml

I want to know what is the difference between `system.log` and `exception.log`.

I usually see logs on SSH by **tail** on all `/var/log tail -f *` but I want to know what part of Magento appears in both files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All Exceptions** are comes in **Exception.log**
When Magento not be able to detect the correct data then it log that in exception.log.

---

**All Php warning , XML-file contains errors and warnings** comes into **System.log**